# How to get all components (Tlabel,Tedit ...) in a form in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I successfully coded a runtime event that changes the size of my `TLabel` when I re-size the form

```
procedure TForm3.pack(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Label1.Font.Size:=Floor(50*(Form3.Width/Screen.Width)*(Form3.Height/Screen.Height));
end;
```

Now I want to get an array of all the components on my form, so I loop on and re-size them.

Any help please, if there is a predefined option or procedure thanks to tell me about it (like responsive)

Thanks

Comment: Use the `Controls[]` property

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ok i ll look for it thanks

Comment: Is this not what anchors are for?

Comment: @TobyAllen i dont know because i started delphi two days ago ( i m 3 years java developer and i migrate by playing some code)

Comment: Play around with anchors on the object properties pallet, you'll see you can automatically resize controls. Set anchors then resize the form.

Comment: @TobyAllen anchors are good but are not like my procedure try it it like a zoom but by a value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the form's `Controls` property. Since all controls inherit from `TControl`, and `TControl` has a `Font` property, it makes it pretty easy (although the property is protected in `TControl`, so you'll need an interposer class):

```
type
  TCtrl = class(TControl);

var
  i: Integer;
  NewSize: Integer;
begin
  NewSize := Floor(50*(Form3.Width/Screen.Width)*(Form3.Height/Screen.Height));
  for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
    TCtrl(Controls[i]).Font.Size := NewSize;
end;
```

Note that some controls (such as `TPanel` and `TTabSheet`) can parent other controls, so they'll have their own `Controls` list. You'll need to loop through those as well.

Comment: You probably need to recurse inside the loop for grandchildren and so on

Comment: Best would be such a method `procedure HandleChildren( Parent: TControl; Action: TProc<TControl>; Filter: TPredicate<TControl>; Recurse: Boolean = False );`. Now you have a global tool

Comment: Probably. The question asked "on my form". I'll leave it to the poster to try and do that; if they can't do so, I can extend it.

Comment: You should only mention the Parent/Child relation. The question itself is answered then. The rest is just sugar :o)

Comment: so i feel that your answer is near to be good only if Font wasn't protect. are you missing something ? may be me ? thanks

Comment: Yep, right you are. Editing (forgot it was protected in TControl).

Comment: @KenWhite i made some thinking and i do some theories on my head if you may to affirm or correct me if i m false:
1- you inherited the TControl class or i may say you wrapped it on a container that you gain full control.
2- the way you did help me to modify (overload) a predefined function on TControl ?
that an exercise i do for me self is to try to guess thinks ( that help when i don't have documentation : improve the logical thinking)

Comment: I created a local descendant of TControl. Descendants have access to protected members of their parent classes. Since we know everything in `Controls[]` is a TControl, the typecast to our new descendent is safe. If you want to alter the behavior of `TControl` itself, you're probably better off doing so in your own descendant; modifying the behavior of all TControl descendants may have side effects you don't expect. As I don't know what you're specifically wanting to modify, I can't offer advice in that area (and comments aren't the appropriate place to try to do so anyway).